# Why can we not use a variable as value of e in C

Tags: c, exponent

my compiler keeps giving me the error that I need to use a digit for this :

xek

where k is supposed to be the power for x using the exponent function e.g:

```
double x ;
for (int k = 1 ; k < 10; k++){

x = 4ek;
}
```

Comment: Please show some actual C code .

Comment: the e notation is for compile time constants, and the value of k is not known until runtim.

Comment: Thanks a lot; however the question has fully been answered below by pmg. `4ek` is not an expression which would raise `4` to the power of `k` where `k` is a variable.

Comment: @Bgie : I think you are the only one answering for `why??` in the OP's question.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C has `e` notation for floating point numbers. It has special format specifier `%e` and `%E` just to print a floating point number in `e` notation. But neither the exponents nor mantissa can be variable. .

`x = 4.0e7;` is perfectly fine.

But to have variable power you need to use standard `math` library functions `exp` or `pow`.

`x = pow(4, k);`

or

`x = 4 * exp(k);`

The way you are using this in a loop, you can optimize it by keeping last calculated value this way: (Assuming `x` is initialized to `1` before loop begins.)

`x = x * 4;`

Every time loop runs `x` is multiplied by `4` hence basically at `k`th loop run `x = 4*exp(k);`.

Answer (score 3):

You need

```
#include <math.h>
pow(x, k);           // x to the power k
x * exp(k);          // x multiplied by e to the k
```